# Aweber does tno allow cron job

Tags: php, api, aweber

I can access this script directly via URL and it works fine but as a cron job ot doesnt work. Is it aweber or am I doing something wrong?

Awebre's documentation is one of the worst ones I have ever come across!

I am not sure why there is no explanation of this in their docs!

Thanks

```html
<?php 
include "wp-load.php";
include_once('wp-includes/class-phpass.php');
$sql = "SELECT member_id, email FROM wp_members_tbl WHERE aweber != 1";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

if(count($result)>0)
 {
  ##Add aweber
  require_once('aweber/aweber_api/aweber_api.php');
  $consumerKey = '***';
  $consumerSecret = '***';
  $accessKey      = '***'; # put your credentials here
  $accessSecret   = '***'; # put your credentials here
  $account_id     = '***'; # put the Account ID here
  $list_id        = '***'; # put the List ID here 3823593   
  $aweber = new AWeberAPI($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
  # Get an access token
  if(empty($_COOKIE['accessToken']))
      {
          if (empty($_GET['oauth_token'])) 
              {
                  $callbackUrl = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                  list($requestToken, $requestTokenSecret) = $aweber->getRequestToken($callbackUrl);
                  setcookie('requestTokenSecret', $requestTokenSecret);
                  setcookie('callbackUrl', $callbackUrl);
                  header("Location: {$aweber->getAuthorizeUrl()}");
                  exit();
              }
          $aweber->user->tokenSecret = $_COOKIE['requestTokenSecret'];
          $aweber->user->requestToken = $_GET['oauth_token'];
          $aweber->user->verifier = $_GET['oauth_verifier'];
          list($accessToken, $accessTokenSecret) = $aweber->getAccessToken();
          setcookie('accessToken', $accessToken);
          setcookie('accessTokenSecret', $accessTokenSecret);
          header('Location: '.$_COOKIE['callbackUrl']);
          exit();
   }
  ##End add aweber

  foreach($result as $val=>$row)
   {
    # Get AWeber Account
     try {
             $account = $aweber->getAccount($_COOKIE['accessToken'], $_COOKIE['accessTokenSecret']);
             $listURL = "https://api.aweber.com/1.0/accounts/***/lists/".$list_id;
             $list = $account->loadFromUrl($listURL);
       $params = array(
                 'email' => $row->email
             );
             $subscribers = $list->subscribers;
             $new_subscriber = $subscribers->create($params);
       $update_data = array('aweber' => 1);
       $where = array('member_id' => $row->member_id);
       $wpdb->update( 'wp_members_tbl', $update_data, $where, $format = null, $where_format = null);
             
                         # success!
             //print "A new subscriber was added to the $list->name list!";
         }
     catch(AWeberAPIException $exc) 
         {
             print "<h3>AWeberAPIException:</h3>";
             print " <li> Type: $exc->type              <br>";
             print " <li> Msg : $exc->message           <br>";
             print " <li> Docs: $exc->documentation_url <br>";
             print "<hr>";
             //exit(1);
         }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a few places where this could be failing:

1) You have relative paths in your includes. The cron may not be able to find the included files. Try changing these to full paths.
2) Your code requires a browser environment (setting cookies, http header Location etc). None of this will work outside of a browser.

You should always execute the file from the command line as the user the cron runs as to test it. Any errors will be obvious.

To fix your issue you should use this tutorial which uses the browser to setup the credentials. After that it can be run from the command line/cron:
http://engineering.aweber.com/quick-start-api-script-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in the cron command:

```
wget -qO- http://yoururlhere/ &> /dev/null
```

It's not the best solution since "self calls" aren't recommended, but it'll keep you from dealing with environment settings.